# How to match only first occurrence of string between strings using RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to match only the first occurrence of a string between other characters. I have looked at a bunch of different answers, but whatever RegEx I try the outcome is always the same, it will not stop at the first match.

This is the content that I'm running through the RegEx:

```
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
https://test.com/1.php?h1=987654321&amp;charge=1234567890&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=
```

And this is my RegEx:

```
(?<=;charge=)([^-]+?)(?=&amp;lang=en&amp;pt=0&amp;w=)
```

Expected outcome:

```
1234567890
```

Actual outcome:

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

[RegExr for the scenario](https://regexr.com/4u3c5) "List" view in Tools should only output 123456789 once. I know it shows 1 match, but list view shows 6. Is it even possible to only get it to come up once?

Comment: This depends on what you are using to run the regex. Your regex is fine and it you probably just need to use a different function in whatever language you are using. Often there is some sort of `matchAll`, `matchFirst`, `matchLast`, etc.

Comment: It can depend on the function you are using, and also on the flags you are providing (it looks like you are using _global_ flag, which you may not want in your case.

Comment: The issue you are experiencing would seem to be a bug/feature of the `RegExr.com` tool you are testing this on (unless you are asking about usage of the tool itself - which would be off-topic on SO). Like you say, it clearly shows "1 match" (and highlights 1 instance) in the top panel, but the list-view shows all matches (as it does with any regex + flags/modifiers it seems). Try a different regex debugger, for example: https://regex101.com/r/tho7Dv/1/